# file name pattern matching and identifying

Tags: data

I have a automation system which manages files sent by multiple client inside S3. It so happens client sends file on a regular basis. Let's not consider the content of the file for time being as it can be something of new data or append on old data.

Typically my files are arranged on a pattern:

```
i) client_a/data_type1/20180610/file_name1_{some_random_text}.csv
ii) client_a/data_type1/20180611/file_name1_{some_random_text}.csv
iii) client_a/data_type1/20180610/file_name2_{some_random_text}.csv
iv) client_a/data_type1/20180611/file_name2_{some_random_text}.csv
v) client_b/data_type2/20180610/file_name3_{some_random_text}.csv
vi) client_b/data_type2/20180611/file_name3_{some_random_text}.csv
vii) client_b/data_type1/20180610/file_name4_{some_random_text}.csv
viii) client_b/data_type1/20180611/file_name4_{some_random_text}.csv
```

This is a sample of the file management. Now I want to be able to be able to identify unique files. For example case i and ii are same files received on different date. But may be separated by some_random_text (usually date or something). 
The primary assumptions here are :

- File name length varies as per client and datatype
- Random text maybe at the first or end of file name for different files but   for not same file. i.e file_name1 will always have random text after the name
- File name extension will vary on different files.

So I want to build a system which takes realtime input of the files received and do an analysis of the name and path to determine if newer version of he same file is received and place it accordingly (same in the sense data may be added to the file).

I have very limited understanding of machine learning algorithms as of whole and not sure which set of algorithms this requires. I am thinking of looking at clustering algorithms. I just want to sure i start in the right direction. Suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify how do you establish that *if newer version of he same file is received*?

Comment: Well we only have the identifier which is file name's initials when we exclude the date. So case i and case ii are same files as the file path is same and file initials are same file_name1_* . Additionally we have a unique ID which is associated with each file that is appended when our automation works. So if the file has same ID then we consider it the same file.

Comment: What programming language do you want to use?

Comment: So, you want to main a list of files without that random number suffix and then on receiving every file, you want to compare if you have received this file before?

Comment: @EliasStrehle We'll I just plan to use python to model my system. But eventually we plan to use java to integrate it into overall system.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yes you are right about that. Actually I want to compare new information inside the file so we need it to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Your example above suggests that you are merely looking for identical filenams in different directories. But in the comments you mention a file ID (is it already available? Do you want to generate it?) and comparing file content. The last part is especially confusing to me: Are you looking for files with _identical_ content? Or for files that _start_ the same, but one is longer (because it is more recent)?

Could you please clarify and perhaps post a more illustrative example?

Comment: @EliasStrehle sorry for the confusion here. The ID is something that is going to be obsolete soon. So we can assume I have a list of paths where I want to identify the files that are the same with file name initials file_name1 and path. So that next time files come into the system I may be able to correctly identify that I have a previous version of the same file and then correctly find the diff, new information added in the content.

Answer (score 1):

This does not sound like a machine learning problem. It seems to me that you could come up with a list of rules that determine whether two files belong together.

As S van Balen said, you should take a look at the `glob` and `re` packages in Python. (If you are on Linux, a Bash script would probably be much more elegant than a solution in Python).

The following links might be helpful:

- Walk through a directory and its subdirectories to get a list of all files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/954522/4743630.
- Group strings in a list based on partial matches (for instance: turn `['file_name1_xyz', 'file_name2_xyz', 'file_name1_abc', 'file_name2_def']` into `[ ['file_name1_xyz', 'file_name1_abc'], ['file_name2_xyz', 'file_name2_def'] ]`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167651/python-iterate-through-a-list-of-strings-and-group-partial-matching-strings.

You mention that files may have different file types. Be careful when converting between types: Make sure for instance that separators and quote characters are treated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the python packages glob and re. I suggest you model the  the logic by hand, of the hip it does't sound like something you want to have searched by a machine learning algorithm.